# Install mysqli on php-7.2.11, but "Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so'"

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, mysqli, php-extension

I have installed the php-7.2.11 on linux successfully but forgot the extensions mysqli.
I made the mysqli.so and installed it on "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718".
If I run the "php -m",there is a mysqli, but when I start the php-fpm,by"
/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -R",it will be failed.the message is :

> **Warning**:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mysqli.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mysqli.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in **Unknown** on line **0**

I don't know why "Unable to load" and why what is the "mysqli.so.so". Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you enable extension mysqli in php.ini?

Comment: yes,I setted :  extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718"  and extension=mysqli.so

Comment: Have you tried commenting on the line in `php.ini` when the library is loading? then execute `$ php -m` you should see the **mysqli** module loaded.  That worked for me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `I made the mysqli.so` ? You created an empty file? or you installed `php7.2-mysql` ?

Answer (score 0):

The php-fmp configuration is usually located separately from php-cli and can be found in `/etc/php/{version}/fpm/php.ini`. Enable extension in it and restart php-fpm service

```
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```